# How to add BioSig extension in EEGlab in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, eeglab, european-data-format

I am working with EEGLAB in Matlab. Now i need **BioSig Plugin** to **export** dataset in **EDF format**.But unfortunatley with EEG extension management is not working . It shows warning message. Is there any other way to add BioSig plugin in EEGLAb??

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just download it (https://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/plugins/BDFimport1.2.zip) and unpack it into the plugins folders (eeglab2021.1\plugins)